# Two different nouns without articles requiring "nicht" and "kein"

Tags: noun, negation

It is my understanding that nouns with indefinite or no articles are negated with "kein"
Example - *Ich habe keinen Hunger*

Why does "kein(en)" becomes "nicht" when we have another noun such as "Hitzefrei"?

As seen here: *Warum haben wir nicht Hitzefrei*?

Comment: Your second sample could be as well _"Warum haben wir kein Hitzefrei"_. There's no such strict requirement as you claim.

Comment: But why is using "nicht" even acceptable here? Shouldn't it be wrong?

Comment: _"Shouldn't it be wrong?"_ Why should it?

Comment: Well, aren't nouns with no or indefinite articles supposed to be negated with "kein(e)" only? Or do we have complete freedom to use "nicht" and "kein" interchangeably?

Comment: _"Or do we have complete freedom to use "nicht" and "kein" interchangeably?"_ No, but there are exceptional and irregular cases as always

Comment: Unfortunately, that sentence was from a standalone exercise. I was just wondering whether it is grammatically correct to replace kein with nicht at will, even with nouns with no articles or indefinite articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general *"kein"* is used with nouns, while *"nicht"* is used with verbs. Some examples stolen from [Handout: Negation with Nicht and Kein](http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/negationexpl.html):

[image]

Since *"Hunger"* is a noun, the usual negation would be *"kein"*, saying *"Nicht Hunger haben"* isn't grammatically incorrect, but quite unusual.

---

Though as always there are examples, where both negations could work well, but with different emphasis.

*"Hitzefrei"* is a noun as *"Hunger"* as well (and not even really translatable to english as a single word. The closest english translation I can think of is *"a (school) day off due to an extraordinary heatwave"*).

The questions

> Warum haben wir nicht Hitzefrei?

and

> Warum haben wir kein Hitzefrei?

would work equally well.

An emphasis from context could be

> Die Klasse 6a hat heute Hitzefrei.
> Warum **haben wir (Klasse 6b) nicht** auch Hitzefrei?

In the above sentence emphasis is more on the verb (*nicht haben*) than onto the noun.

Though

> Die Klasse 6a hat heute Hitzefrei.
> Warum haben wir (Klasse 6b) **kein Hitzefrei**?

still would work equally well, but emphasis shifts slightly to the noun (*kein Hitzefrei*).

---

The english translations could be

> Class 6a got a day off for the extraordinary heatwave.
> Why did we (class 6b) **not get** a day off?
>
> Class 6a got a day off for the extraordinary heatwave.
> Why did we (class 6b) get **no day off** as well?

It seems that's bit of an exception / irregularity, and you can't really apply a strict grammar rule.